# Parsing emails problems

Tags: python, parsing, email

I'm having problems with decoding emails that that I'm fetching.

The script should log on to an email account, get the unread messages and then later on store them in a database. I only want the actual text from the email but none of the html stuff.

I have found many examples but none of the seems to work.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787739/python-email-get-payload-decode-fails-when-hitting-equal-sign) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331351/python-email-header-decoding-utf-8) and some more I have found.

The Code I have now:

```
import imaplib, sys, email
import email.parser

myparser = email.parser.Parser()
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host='mail.something.com')

retcode, capabilities = conn.login('username', 'XXXXX')

conn.select('Inbox', readonly = 1) # Select inbox as read-only
retcode, messages = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
if retcode == 'OK':
    for message in messages[0].split(' '):
        if message == '':
            continue
         ret, data = conn.fetch(message,'(RFC822)')
         msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
#        rootMessage = myparser.parse(data[0][1])

#        print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (message, rootMessage)
        print msg
        print '---------------------------------------------------------------' 

 conn.close()
```

As you can see there is no decoding in this because everything that I have tried has failed.

I am very new to python so if someone could steer me into the right direction I would really appreciate it. A hack would be all right, it not a mission critical script, but a generic solution would be best.

-G

UPDATE:

There is no error, the problem is that the output is not decoded correctly.

Example input:

```
 This is a test message.

 Gísli
```

Output:

```
 This is a test message.

 G=EDsli
```

Comment: What failed? Please tell exact steps and error messages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help:

```
import quopri

print quopri.decodestring(msg).decode('utf8')
```

Or this:

```
import base64  

body = base64.b64decode(msg)
```

Comment: I get an error if I try this: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 222-227: unsupported Unicode code range   . Any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove `.decode('utf8')` or replace `'utf8'` with your email message coding

Comment: Thanks. This is getting me somewhere. I had forgot to change the encoding to iso-8859-1 .